# Mixed 10Gbps/25Gpbs on Supermicro AOC-A25G-b2SM (BCM57414)

Tags: networking, nic, supermicro

Working on installing some new Supermicro servers and they're configured with a AOC-A25G-b2SM NIC (2xSFP28 ports). Based on what we can support with our switches, we were planning to do a primary link at 25Gbps and have the second one run at 10Gbps. From my testing so far, I can only get the following combinations of link speeds to work:

25/25
10/10
1/25

Is there a limitation on this NIC that wont let me run one port at 25 and the other at 10? I didn't see anything in the datasheet or manual about this limitation, but everything I've tried seems to prevent it.

When one link is at 25Gbps, ethtool shows the options for the other at 1000 or 25000.
Alternatively, when one link is running at 10000, it shows 10000 or 1000 as options.

Tried to force ethtool to set 10000 on link 2 when link 1 was at 25000, and it just failed.

Comment: 10GBit is just for compatibility, same as 1GBit. Invest in new 25GBit switches or use an additional 10GBit NIC.

Comment: for a windows or Linux teaming nope, it just may look a wired 35gbit connection ;) we used a similar situation for a backup server where we used the 25gb for the NAS and 2x 10gbit for the usual network.